# What does $f(x,y) = x + y$ mean in graphing?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, graphing-functions

All right, so I'm supposed to graph these $5$ things:
$$x \geq 3\\
x\leq 6\\
y \geq 3\\
y \leq 6\\
f(x,y) = x + y$$

I was able to graph the first four, but I have no idea what the last one means. I searched it up on Google and I found 3-D images, so I'm absolutely clueless on what to do here.

Comment: This is a good question- I was wondering the same. Let me know, in that case I can edit my answer.

Comment: I suspect asking your teacher would be better than asking here; they know what they meant, we don't.

Comment: I agree with your search results. The graph of $f$ is a 3D image. I'm not sure if your teacher (or ...) expects you to do that freehand, and what it's supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2):

So, my understanding is that you need help understanding the intuition of what a function of two variables looks like graphically. My advice is to consider the limiting behavior in a few directions.

Consider the following cases. What if we follow the path $y=x$ on in the $xy-$plane? We can see that as $(x,y)\to\infty$, $f(x,y)\to\infty$. So, based on the situation, we should imagine that the function increases linearly, because $y=x\implies f(x,x)=2x=2y$. What about along the $x$ and $y$ axes?

Along the $x-$axis, we can see that our function is $f(x,0)=x$. So, we should imagine the function increasing linearly, with half the rate of change of along $x=y$. Likewise for $f(0,y)=y$. Now consider the line $y=-x$. We can see that along this line, $f(x,-x)=0$, and so the line orthogonal to $y=x$ is $0$. This should paint the picture of a plane in your head, but just in case, maybe we should look at some points.

$f(1,1)=2$, $f(1,0)=1$, $f(0,1)=1$, $f(0,0)=0$, $f(1,-1)=0$, $f(-1,1)=0$, $f(-1,-1)=-2.$ Plotting these on a $3-$dimensional grid should give a clear idea of the image: a plane. Here's an image.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm only an Algebra student. I don't understand this.

Comment: What is unclear? Let me know how I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in assuming that it is three-dimensional.  For the sake of simplicity, let's replace $f(x,y)$ with $z$.  So now we can say $z = x+y$.  So, the bigger $x$ gets, the bigger $z$ gets, and the bigger $y$ gets, the bigger $z$ gets.  Now draw three-dimensional axes (if you've ever done any drafting or AutoCAD, just imagine the isometric view), and call the vertical axis $z$, the horizontal axis $y$, and the diagonal axis $x$.  If both $x$ and $y$ are very large, $z$ is very large.  If both $x$ and $y$ are very small, $z$ is very small.  Now thing about when $x$ is negative and $y$ is positive, or vice versa.  Can you visualize what will happen to $z$?  When is $z=0$?